When I click on the button, database information for the relevant button does not appear
I am pulling data from the MySQL database to a page. There is a select button on each line. When I click on this button, a section with details of that data appears. When I press the Close button, I return to the page with all the records. But when I click on the Select button, I can only get the id information. What I want is to show the database information with that ID information in the detail section. Only the ID of the record I clicked appears in the detail section.
I currently have 1 php page and I apply the commands there. I am pulling all records from the database to this page. There is no problem in this part. I add a select button to each line and add <td><div class='select' id=".$cek['sira_no']." onclick='callup_arrays(this.id)'>Select</div></td> code. Then I code this function as follows.
<script>
const details = document.querySelector(".details");
const usertab = document.querySelector("#usertab");
const user = document.querySelector("#user");
const close = document.querySelector("#close");

close.addEventListener("click", function () {
  usertab.style.display = "table";
  details.style.display = "none";
});
function callup_arrays(clicked_id) {
  usertab.style.display = "none";
  user.innerHTML = clicked_id;
 
  details.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

Afterwards
<div class="details">
  <button id="close">Close</button>
  <br>
  <br>
    
  <h2>Ski Resort Sequence Number</h2>
 <p id="user"></p>

  
</div>

Whatever button I click on in the details section with the code, the ID of that button appears. But I can only transfer ID information. What I want is this:
There are many records with the same id in the database. I want to display these records in the details section in the form of a table.
There is actually an id that is unique. But here I have a few lines of information about a ski resort. 1 use ticket, x ski resorts, adult x dollars, child x dollars. 5-use ticket, same ski resort, 3x dollars for adults, 2x dollars for children. That's why I want to pull information about that ski resort. Here, I can also filter with the code I gave to that ski resort. I can also filter by the name of the ski resort.
My code is like this
<table id="usertab" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sıra No</th>
            <th>Bulunduğu İl</th>
            <th>Kayak Merkezi</th>
            <!-- <th><div class="select" id="5" onclick="callup_arrays(this.id)">Select</div></th>  -->
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody class=”usertab”>
            <?php 
            
            
            $sec="SELECT DISTINCT(merkez),il,sira_no FROM skipass ORDER BY sira_no";
            $sonuc=$conn->query($sec);
            
            if($sonuc->num_rows>0){
                while($cek=$sonuc->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>".$cek['sira_no']."</td>
                            <td>".$cek['il']."</td>
                            <td>".$cek['merkez']."</td>
                            <td><div class='select' id=".$cek['sira_no']." onclick='callup_arrays(this.id)'>Select</div></td>
                        </tr>
                        ";
                }
            
            }else{
            
            echo "Veritabanında Kayıt Bulunamadı";
            }
                ?>
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Sıra No</th>
            <th>Bulunduğu İl</th>
            <th>Kayak Merkezi</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
    
    
    
<div class="details">
  <button id="close">Close</button>
  <br>
  <br>
    
  <h2>Kayak Merkezi Sıra No</h2>
  <p id="user"></p>

  
</div>
<script>
const details = document.querySelector(".details");
const usertab = document.querySelector("#usertab");
const user = document.querySelector("#user");
const close = document.querySelector("#close");

close.addEventListener("click", function () {
  usertab.style.display = "table";
  details.style.display = "none";
});
function callup_arrays(clicked_id) {
  usertab.style.display = "none";
  user.innerHTML = clicked_id;
 
  details.style.display = "block";
}
</script>


usertab.style.display = "table";   // try to use block instead of table                                                                     usertab.style.display = "block";

Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem? "There are many records with the same id in the database" - why is that the case? Usually, an ID should be unique

There is actually an id that is unique. But here I have a few lines of information about a ski resort.
1 use ticket, x ski resorts, adult x dollars, child x dollars. 5-use ticket, same ski resort, 3x dollars for adults, 2x dollars for children. That's why I want to pull information about that ski resort. Here, I can also filter with the code I gave to that ski resort. I can also filter by the name of the ski resort.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Issue:
The issue lies in the following function:
function callup_arrays(clicked_id) {
   usertab.style.display = "none";
   user.innerHTML = clicked_id;

   details.style.display = "block";
}

In the line user.innerHTML = clicked_id;, you are simply setting the innerHTML of the user element to the clicked_id. This is why only the id is being displayed in the details section.
Solution:
To resolve this, I recommend using AJAX. When this function is called, it should send a GET request to a PHP file. The PHP file would receive the id via the GET request, process it, and fetch the corresponding record from the database. The PHP file should then return the full details as a response. Once the function receives this data, it can dynamically render the details in a structured HTML format.
